# CClientScript duplicates the output

Tags: yii

I'm trying to use this extension in a partial view, in my `registration` module...

```
$form->widget('ext.tokenInput.TokenInput', array(
    'model' => $model,
    'attribute' => 'tags',
    'url' => array('wizard/search'),
    'options' => array(
        'allowCreation' => false,
        'preventDuplicates' => true,
        'allowFreeTagging' => false,
        'minChars' => 2,
        'theme' => 'facebook',
    )
));
```

...and assets (javascript and CSS files) are duplicated. 
Basically I can see in the HTML code multiple occurrences of these files. 
I have the same problem if I try to add custom JS files in the same partial view.
I specify `POS_HEAD` and I can see the code in `<head>` and in the middle of the page.
Why CClientScript duplicates assets if I add them in a partial view?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: are you doing ajax request?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#renderPartial-detail processOutput parameter should be false.

Comment: Thanks! Solved! It was a wrong parameter in the renderPartial()